# Android :WindowManager$BadTockenException on Spinner Click

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner in my home.class. When I click on the spinner, the process is stopped showing exception that WindowManager$BadTockenException is caught.

I am calling this home.class from main.class which extends ActivityGroup.

If I am simply run only the home.class, the spinner is showing all items. But the problem is only with calling home.class from main.class.

The following are my code. Please tell me why this is happened.

### main.class

```
public class main extends ActivityGroup
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Intent intent=new Intent(this,home.class);
       View view=getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("1", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
       setContentView(view);
  }
```

}

### home.class

```
String[] country={"Please selects","US","INDIA","UK"};
Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCountry=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
adapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s2.setAdapter(adapterCountry);

s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
     public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
     {
            countryName=country[position];
     }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
     {
            countryName=country[0];
      }
```

});

### Stack

Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException))
    AlertDialog(Dialog).show() line: 245
    AlertDialog$Builder.show() line: 802
    Spinner.performClick() line: 260
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 9080
    ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3647
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Thank You....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error may be with the setContentView given inside your home.class.

Instead of `setContentView(yourlayout);`

give,

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(yourlayout, null);
this.setContentView(viewToLoad);  
Spinner s2 = (Spinner) viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
```

And give your spinner code as:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCountry=new ArrayAdapter(this.getParent(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
adapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s2.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
```

Since you are using activity group, you face this issue. Hope this solution may help you.

Comment: man this saved me, also to note is you still have to pass getParent() into your AlertDialogs and such...But this certainly fixes the Spinner issue...