# BadTokenException when click on spinner in an ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabs, spinner, activitygroup

I searched now for two days for a solution, but i didnt find something that work.

I have a TabHost with 4 tabs and change can change the view from the first tab to another where i have a spinner. This spinner get initialized correct, but I'm not able to click on it, cause if I do I get an BadTokenException

```
07-28 13:52:59.446: E/AndroidRuntime(692): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@405496d8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Now to Code:

```
viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.projekt_daten, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

To understand some Variables my function call

```
fuelleSpinner("SELECT _id, name FROM kunden", R.id.s_kundenauswahl);
```

So i fill the spinner:

```
private void fuelleSpinner(String selection, int spinnerID){

    Cursor spinnerCursor = mDatenbank.rawQuery(selection, null);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerID);
    String[] data = new String[spinnerCursor.getCount()];

    for(int i = 0; i  adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter(getParent(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I also tried this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getParent(), R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Both ways initialize the spinner correctly, but if i click on the spinner the app crashes.

Comment: Check out the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665931/android-windowmanagerbadtockenexception-on-spinner-click

Comment: It didnt work, same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.XXXX, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```