# Error when clicking on spinner in a popup window

Tags: android, spinner, popupwindow

I'm making a program in which I have a spinner in a popup window but it turns out when I click on the spinner I get an error and exits the application, and do not understand that, please I'm desperate, I need your help, thank you very much in advance =)

```
public void añadirRegistro(View v){

     showPopup(leer_registros.this);
}
private void showPopup(final Activity context) {

       Spinner eleccionIP,eleccionRegistro;
       borrar_datos BorrarDatos = new borrar_datos ();
       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);
       eleccionIP = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
       eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);



       /*Cursor cur=BorrarDatos.obtenerIP();
       BorrarDatos.rellenarSpinner(cur,eleccionIP);*/


       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
       popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popup.setFocusable(true);

       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 200, 200);


       ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      adapter.add("item 1");
      adapter.add("item 2");
      eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

in logcat tells me nothing and I jump directly to debug only, which tells me:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException))   
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    WindowManagerGlobal.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams, Display, Window) line: 255    
    WindowManagerImpl.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams) line: 69    
    PopupWindow.invokePopup(WindowManager$LayoutParams) line: 993   
    PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(View, int, int) line: 899    
    Spinner$DropdownPopup(ListPopupWindow).show() line: 603 
    Spinner$DropdownPopup.show() line: 981  
    Spinner.performClick() line: 609    
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 17355 
    Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
    ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Post error log please

Comment: can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

It seem your forgot to set your view to Content.

```
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);
this.setContentView(layout);
```

[Reference link: Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4666072/646806)

Comment: if I do what you tell me also gives me error, but this time not shows me the popup

Comment: Doesn't help that reference link?

Comment: no I have not worked, still gives me the same error =( I'm desperate!